# A special type of differential equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Working in optimal control of PDEs, I came across a type of evolution problem that has instead of an initial condition a link between the initial state and the final state.
Here is a simplified version of the problem:

$$
\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}(t,x)=d\Delta y(t,x)+ f(y(t,x)),\ (t,x)\in (0,T)\times\Omega\\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\nu}=0,\ (t,x)\in (0,T)\times\partial\Omega \\ y(0,x)=y(T,x)+g(x),\ x\in\Omega \end{cases}
$$

Hereabove $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded and smooth domain.

> Is there some theory regarding the existence, uniqueness and regularity of the solution? I will be thankful if you can indicate me some references (article or books) from where I can learn something. It's the first time I see this type of problem and I did not succeed in finding something about it.

At a first glance there are many cases in which there is no solution.